# indexof() not selecting the first instance of string

Tags: javascript, select, html-select, indexof

been trying to figure this out for some time now and I can't seem to do it.

I have this for casperjs

```
    var size = this.evaluate(function () {
    var  number = 10;

            var size;
            $('select[name="placeholder"] option[name="plId"]')
                .each(function (index, dom) {
                    var currentsize = $(dom).attr('value');
                    if (String(currentsize).indexOf(
                        String(number)) > -1) {
                        size = currentsize;
                    }
                });
            return size;
        });
```

and I'm trying to select 10 from the value

```
<option name="plId" value="25437456:10" data-label="(10)">10</option>
<option name="plId" value="53467763:10.5" data-label="(10.5)">10.5</option>
```

but for some reason it selects 10.5 every time, when it should select 10.

Anyone know what's wrong? Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.each()` loop processes every element. So the `size` variable will end up being the *last* item that matched rather than the first.

You can stop the loop as soon as you have a match by returning `false` from within the function you passed to `.each()`.

```
var size = this.evaluate(function() {
      var number = 10;

      var size;
      $('select[name="placeholder"] option[name="plId"]')
        .each(function(index, dom) {
          var currentsize = $(dom).attr('value');
          if (String(currentsize).indexOf(
            String(number)) > -1) {
            size = currentsize;
            return false;  // <--- ADD THIS
          }
        });
      return size;
    });
```